# ReactTable - Toggle row background color onClick/ onExpandRow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

in ReactTable I want to make the row background color toggle when that row is expanded.  In the link below, the first image is what I have, the second is what I want it to be. I've tried playing around with onExpandedChange and a few things without success. Any idea how to accomplish this.  Thanks for any help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6OoI.jpg

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme), you can use custom props (there is no direct link to the example, try search for `You can use these callbacks for dynamic styling as well!`):

```
   <ReactTable
      getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
        return {
          style: {
            background: state.expanded[rowInfo.index] ? "blue" : "white"
          }
        };
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, that worked great.  It didn't seem to toggle, the blue row would remain after collapsing the row, but I did this and it worked.  Very similar.
`return state.expanded[rowInfo.index]
              ? {
                  style: {
                    background: "#3e88c4",
                    color: "white"
                  }
                }
              : "";`

Comment: @AugustusBrennan Glad it helps. Updated answer :)